# How to import this excel format into this database format?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a question about import excel cells data into sqlserver database. But my excel data looks like below:

```
ID|NAME    |DAY1   |DAY2   |DAY3   |DAY4   |  
--+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+  
1 |John Doe|shift-1|shift-1|shift-1|shift-1|
--------------------------------------------
2 |Alex    |shift-2|shift-2|shift-2|shift-2|
--------------------------------------------
3 |McArthur|shift-3|shift-3|shift-3|shift-3|
--------------------------------------------
```

and my database format looks loke below:

```
DateTime|ID|NAME    |SCHEDULE|
--------+--+--------+--------+
DAY1    |1 |John Doe|Shift-1 |
------------------------------
DAY1    |2 |Alex    |Shift-2 |
------------------------------
DAY1    |3 |McArthur|Shift-3 |
------------------------------
DAY2    |1 |John Doe|Shift-1 |
------------------------------
DAY2    |2 |Alex    |Shift-2 |
------------------------------
DAY2    |3 |McArthur|Shift-3 |
------------------------------
DAY3    |1 |John Doe|Shift-1 |
------------------------------
DAY3    |2 |Alex    |Shift-2 |
------------------------------
DAY3    |3 |McArthur|Shift-3 |
------------------------------
DAY4    |1 |John Doe|Shift-1 |
------------------------------
DAY4    |2 |Alex    |Shift-2 |
------------------------------
DAY4    |3 |McArthur|Shift-3 |
```

and i tried wrote a code, and offcourse its not right.

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("Can't Open");
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024))
{
$cnt = count($csv_line);
for($i=1;$i<=$cnt;$i++){
    $data[$i]['ID']   = $csv_line[1];
    $data[$i]['NAME'] = $csv_line[2];
    $data[$i]['DAY1'] = $csv_line[3];
    $data[$i]['DAY2'] = $csv_line[4];
    $data[$i]['DAY3'] = $csv_line[5];
    $data[$i]['DAY4'] = $csv_line[6];
}
    return $data;
}
    fclose($fp) or die("Error");
```

Its possible to do it? because my company dont want to change the old excel format because will impact to all branches.

Comment: My below answer fits if you have this same table structure on database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to group your data by the day values, you need to organise your loop that way too, creating one entry for each day from every line read from the file. Something like this:

```
$data = array();
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
    $data[] = array('DATETIME' => 'DAY1', 'ID' => $csv_line[0], 'NAME' => $csv_line[1], 'SCHEDULE' => $csv_line[2]);
    $data[] = array('DATETIME' => 'DAY2', 'ID' => $csv_line[0], 'NAME' => $csv_line[1], 'SCHEDULE' => $csv_line[3]);
    $data[] = array('DATETIME' => 'DAY3', 'ID' => $csv_line[0], 'NAME' => $csv_line[1], 'SCHEDULE' => $csv_line[4]);
    $data[] = array('DATETIME' => 'DAY4', 'ID' => $csv_line[0], 'NAME' => $csv_line[1], 'SCHEDULE' => $csv_line[5]);
}
```

You should then be able to insert each row of the `$data` array into your database e.g.

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    // insert $d into database
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. BTW, how to ignore the headers?

Comment: @Roman good to hear. If you know there will always be a header line, you could just add `fgetcsv($fp, 1024);` before the while loop to read it and throw it away, or possibly save the results and use them to change the `DATETIME` values in the array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Unpivot* to get your desired result. But this works on database end. First you'll put this record as it is in database then use Unpivot to convert the record in your desired format.

```
    GO
    SELECT [datetime], id, name, schedule  
    FROM   
       (SELECT id, name, Day1, day2, day3, day4 
       FROM pvt) p  
    UNPIVOT  
       (schedule FOR [datetime] IN   
          (Day1, day2, day3, day4)  
    )AS unpvt;  
    GO
```

You may use this output for insertion in your table.